# How can I use loop in input and form?

Tags: reactjs

I have a from with 3 input that I want show value of them in console, but I don't know how can I use loop for them, can you help me please?

```
<form onSubmit={props.submitData} className="center-content-product">
<div className="left">
<p>Name:</p>
<p>Password:</p>
<p>Email:</p>
</div>

<div className="right">
<Input change={props.changeData} />
<Input change={props.changeData} />
<Input change={props.changeData} />
</div>

<button type="submit" value="Send" className="send-btn" >Submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Not sure if this solves your problem

```
<form onSubmit={props.submitData} className="center-content-product">
<div className="left">
<p>Name:</p>
<p>Password:</p>
<p>Email:</p>
</div>

<div className="right">
{Array.from(Array(3), (e, i) => {
    return <Input key={i} change={props.changeData} />
  })}
</div>

<button type="submit" value="Send" className="send-btn" >Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: it made 3 input correctly, but it doesn't show value of them correctly, it just show last one input value

Comment: Coz its not a list. So the last value is saved. `props.changeData` must be changed

Comment: how can I do that? could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

salam

you can create variable for props.changeData

or

if this variable your state you can create state .

```js
   let changeData = props.changeData;

   {changeData.map(item => <input change={item.your_data}/>)}
```

i recommend use [formik](https://formik.org/)

Comment: can I have your email address please?

Comment: @Parisa 

jafarchoupan@gmail.com

Comment: @Parisa , i just recommend formik 

my solution not dependent to formik .